# How to move player to cursor without click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, move

I want to make a script where the player moves towards the mouse pointer, and this when not clicking any button.

So far, I managed to only make a move to click point, but if I need to change direction, I need to click again.

How can I move the player towards cursor at all times, without even clicking something? (Maybe right click for initialization)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html).

Just a few notes:

1. The coordinates are in Pixel Coordinates, you might need to convert them in World Coordintes to properly move your player.
2. The position is read even if the mouse is outside of the game screen. You have to manually take care of that (depending on how the game should behave).